# UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext rotate the image at will?

Tags: iphone, rotation, cgcontext

In brief, the app is meant to do the following:

1. The user will select from the photos within the iPhone (via ALAssets).  This part is fine.
2. The selected photo will appear on another view, within a smaller, rectangular subview.
3. When using the ALAsset thumbnail, the image shows up correctly within the subview.  However, the resolution is poor, so I'm trying to use a higher resolution image.
4. When using the full resolution image, and then placing it into the view, any portrait photo will be rotated 90 degrees counter-clockwise.

Code-wise, this it looks like this:

```
//ImageView is the UIImageView subview that will hold the selected photo image.
//This code works ok, but I'd rather have a higher resolution photo.
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[selectedPhoto thumbnail]];
```

Now, this is the code where I try to use a higher resolution image, but then the image within imageView is rotated -90 degrees:

```
[imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

//HIGH RESOLUTION IMAGE
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [selectedPhoto defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
if (iref) 
{
   UIImage *largeImage = [Utilities imageWithImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:iref] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(CGImageGetWidth(iref)/4, CGImageGetHeight(iref)/4)]; 
   [imageView setImage:largeImage];
}
```

And the imageWithImage: function called there looks like this:

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

As mentioned, photos taken in landscape orientation by the iPhone camera come out OK.  However, photos taken in portrait camera orientation come out rotated -90 degrees somehow.

How can I make it so that each photo, whether taken in portrait or landscape, will come out oriented correctly on my ImageView?

Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: I found the answer here!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648632/alassetrepresentation-fullresolutionimages-uiimageorientation-is-wrong

I am doing this now:

ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [selectedPhoto defaultRepresentation];
CGImageRef iref = [rep fullResolutionImage];
UIImage *largeImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:iref scale:4 orientation:rep.orientation];

PS. I couldnt answer the question yet, since not enough time has passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer here!

[ALAssetRepresentation fullResolutionImage's UIImageOrientation is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648632/alassetrepresentation-fullresolutionimages-uiimageorientation-is-wrong)

I am doing this now:

UIImage *largeImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:iref scale:4 orientation:(UIImageOrientation)rep.orientation];